# How to call Chef resource inside ruby_block in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm trying to call the Chef resource inside ruby_block. Anyone can tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
file '/tmp/arockia/storage.txt' do
end

lines = `cat /tmp/arockia/storage.txt | wc -l`
ruby_block 'Check for content' do
    block do
            lines = `cat /tmp/arockia/storage.txt | wc -l`
            if Integer(lines) == 0
                    r = Chef::Resource::Execute.new('Get-Disk-Storage',run_context)
                    r.command 'df -kh >> /tmp/arockia/storage.txt'
                    r.run_action :run
            end
    end
end
```

Comment: What's not working / the error message?

Comment: There is no error @StephenKing . It says "execute the ruby block Check for content"

Comment: Have you tried reducing it to a minimal example, i.e. remove the `if` condition?

Comment: It worked with resources(:execute => "Get-Disk-Storage").run_action(:run)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
require 'mixlib/shellout'

file '/tmp/arockia/storage.txt' do
  action :create_if_missing
  contents lazy { shell_out!('df -kh').stdout }
  not_if do
    ::File.file?('/tmp/arockia/storage.txt') && \
      ::File.size('/tmp/arockia/storage.txt') > 0
  end
end
```

?

Backticks in a Chef recipe are generally a bad idea.  https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#shelling-out

Updated to include coderanger's suggestion in comment.

Comment: Thank you so much @Karen B.

Comment: This is still wrong, the correct code would be `contents lazy { shell_out!('df -kh').stdout }`. Using the `shell_out!` helper makes sure you get the Chef logging setup and also that it will raise an exception if the command fails. Additionally you need the `lazy{}` because the `contents` property doesn't natively accept a block.